# Probability of meeting an infected person in a room

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been invited to a wedding party, but because of COVID-19, I am thinking about whether to participate or not. Let's say 100 people should take part in the party. All people are from the region, where 728 inhabitants are currently infected with COVID-19, 66 people cured. One person died in the region. The region itself has a population of 250 000. What is the probability of meeting an infected person at the wedding?

**EDIT**
My thoughts are these: If there is circa 700 currently infected known cases, the actual number could be 10 times bigger (because of mild or asymptomatic cases). So, the probability that someone in the region has the infection is $\frac{7000}{250000}$, 2.8 %. Therefore the probability, that a person doesn't have the infection is 97.2 %. At the party will be 100 participants, the probability that **nobody** will have the infection is $0.972^{100}$, which is about 0.0584 (5.84 %). In conclusion, the probability that there will be **someone** at the party with the infection is 94.16 %.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  You'll have to make some obviously unrealistic assumptions, like that infected people are as likely to attend a party as are uninfected people.

Comment: Your comment is on point, but the problem is that people with COVID often don't have any symptoms at all. So, in my scenario, I don't distinguish that an infected person would not attend the party. It is the worst-case scenario.

Comment: So, go ahead and make that assumption.  What's the answer in that case?

Comment: I have edited the question with my assumption.

Comment: You said there were $728$ infected people, not $7000$.  Also, that calculation only works if you assume independence, which isn't strictly accurate.  Better to compute $\binom {25000-728}{100}\Big / \binom {25000}{100}$.

Comment: To be clear:  it isn't terrible to assume independence.  It's roughly true so you get an approximation that way.  But if you can handle the proper calculation, it should be more accurate.

Comment: There are 700 reported cases, the actual number will be much higher. Anyway, I don't understand your calculation. Why is there 25000 instead of 250000 and what the 100 represents?

Comment: About the 100, I got it. It is the number of participants. I was confused.

Comment: Yes, it should have been $250000$.  We have no information about the unreported cases.  You can make a guess, if you like, but that's not a math question.

Comment: We still know not enough about this virus to make even a rough guess. There are several factors that make this virus particular dangerous (and unpredictable), for example the long time it can take until a person gets ill. So, the only advice can be that you avoid parties the next few months at least, I would tend to be even more pessimistic - the battle against such an aggressive variant will take years, in the worst case decades.